# How to create an additional attribute in Active Directory from VBScript?

Tags: iis, vbscript, active-directory, asp-classic

Is it possible to create an additional attribute in Active Directory from VBScript, or do I inevitably have to first create it in the AD Schema?

When I try to set a new attribute, let's say "**newattr123**" with the *.setInfo()* and *.put()* methods, I get an error stating that this attribute is not yet defined in the AD.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Judging by these search results, creating a new custom attribute doesn't seem to be possible via VBScript. At least not that I can see a solution to scripting the steps explained:

https://msexchangeguru.com/2015/11/19/ad_creating_custom_attribute/

https://fkazi.blogspot.com/2013/04/creating-custom-active-directory_27.html

For anything else AD related, [SelfADSI](http://www.selfadsi.org/) is a good source of information.

Comment: Thank you @Hel O'Ween ! In fact, your search results gie the same light as mine. Reading and manipulating **AD Attributes** values is possible via VBScript, but their definition in the **AD Schema** is not. I will dig the provided links to create the additional attributes I need, and I thank you VERY MUCH for ***SelfADSI*** : I did not knew this useful resource indeed!